# To call converter from ControlTemplate string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to bind controlTemplate to  in generic.xaml.My controlTemplate has converter in it.While binding,its throwing an exception as `Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception`.

In MyView.cs

```
 templateString = @"<ControlTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"" >
                                            <Canvas><Polygon Points=""{Binding Size,Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter}}"" Fill=""red""/></Canvas>
                                       </ControlTemplate>";

this.Template = XamlReader.Load(new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(new StringReader(templateString ))) as ControlTemplate;
```

In generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:MySample"
                    xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationFramework"
                    xmlns:srcview="clr-namespace:MySample.Views"
                    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MySample.Converters"
                    >
    <converters:SizeConverter x:Key="SizeConverter" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type srcview:MyView}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type srcview:MyView}">      
                   <Canvas>
                      <ContentControl Template="{TemplateBinding Template}" Name="contentControl" >                      
                      </ContentControl>

                   </Canvas>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

How to fix this issue??

Comment: Could you explain in detail what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

One normally gets this problem when the static resources are not defined before referencing them.

For a test, try reading an xaml usercontrol with a static resource defined in the resources section of the xaml. If that works then you know the problem is not with referencing the converter, but rather when and were it is defined.

A faster way to ensure that the converter is actually being loaded is to put it in the app.xaml. This will ensure that the resource dictionary is loaded at startup. Here follows an example:

```
<Application x:Class="TeslaFrame.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:metro="http://schemas.codeplex.com/elysium"
         >
 <Application.Resources>      
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Elysium;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="globalBoolToVisConverter" />                 
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```